# Save data to a file when a button is clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making an application for a ledcube in C#.
All it does now is allow the user to click on some buttons to change the color of the desired led's. 
I'm trying to imply a function which allows the user to save the current configuration (of colors) to a file, which later can be read by a programming bord.
The saved file must contain binary code for each led (whether the led is on, and which color: off, red, green, orange).
I was thinking that 1 led can contain a value between 00 - 11 (so 0 and 3).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Button[,] laag_1 = new Button[8, 8];
    Button[,] laag_2 = new Button[8, 8];
    Button[,] laag_3 = new Button[8, 8];
    Button[,] laag_4 = new Button[8, 8];
    Button[,] laag_5 = new Button[8, 8];
    Button[,] laag_6 = new Button[8, 8];
    Button[,] laag_7 = new Button[8, 8];
    Button[,] laag_8 = new Button[8, 8];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_1.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_1.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                laag_1[x, y] = new Button();
                laag_1[x, y].SetBounds((50 * x) + 100, (50 * y) + 30, 40, 40);
                laag_1[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_click);
                Controls.Add(laag_1[x, y]);
                laag_1[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_2.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_1.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                laag_2[x, y] = new Button();
                laag_2[x, y].SetBounds((50 * x) + 520, (50 * y) + 30, 40, 40);
                laag_2[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_click);
                Controls.Add(laag_2[x, y]);
                laag_2[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_3.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_3.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                laag_3[x, y] = new Button();
                laag_3[x, y].SetBounds((50 * x) + 940, (50 * y) + 30, 40, 40);
                laag_3[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_click);
                Controls.Add(laag_3[x, y]);
                laag_3[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_4.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_4.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                laag_4[x, y] = new Button();
                laag_4[x, y].SetBounds((50 * x) + 1360, (50 * y) + 30, 40, 40);
                laag_4[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_click);
                Controls.Add(laag_4[x, y]);
                laag_4[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_5.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_5.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                laag_5[x, y] = new Button();
                laag_5[x, y].SetBounds((50 * x) + 100, (50 * y) + 520, 40, 40);
                laag_5[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_click);
                Controls.Add(laag_5[x, y]);
                laag_5[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_6.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_6.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                laag_6[x, y] = new Button();
                laag_6[x, y].SetBounds((50 * x) + 520, (50 * y) + 520, 40, 40);
                laag_6[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_click);
                Controls.Add(laag_6[x, y]);
                laag_6[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_7.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_7.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                laag_7[x, y] = new Button();
                laag_7[x, y].SetBounds((50 * x) + 940, (50 * y) + 520, 40, 40);
                laag_7[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_click);
                Controls.Add(laag_7[x, y]);
                laag_7[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_8.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_8.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                laag_8[x, y] = new Button();
                laag_8[x, y].SetBounds((50 * x) + 1360, (50 * y) + 520, 40, 40);
                laag_8[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_click);
                Controls.Add(laag_8[x, y]);
                laag_8[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(this.SaveEventHandler);
        LoadFromFile();
    }

    void btnEvent_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control ctrl = ((Control)sender);
        switch (ctrl.BackColor.Name)
        {
            case "Red":
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;
            case "Black":
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case "Green":
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                break;
            case "Yellow":
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Black;
                break;
            default:
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Black;
                break;
        }
    }

    void SaveEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveToFile();
    }

    private const string filePath = @"C:\testmap\laag_1.txt";
    private void LoadFromFile()
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            return;

        byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        if (data == null || data.Length != laag_1.GetLength(0) * laag_1.GetLength(1) * 2)
            return;

        for (int x = 0; x < laag_1.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_1.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                int position = (y * laag_1.GetLength(0) + x);

                string value = ((char)data[2 * position]).ToString() + ((char)data[2 * position + 1]).ToString();
                Color color;
                switch (value)
                {
                    case "01":
                        color = Color.Red;
                        break;
                    case "00":
                        color = Color.Black;
                        break;
                    case "10":
                        color = Color.Green;
                        break;
                    case "11":
                        color = Color.Yellow;
                        break;
                    default:
                        color = Color.Black;
                        break;
                }

                laag_1[x, y].BackColor = color;
            }
        }

    }

    private void SaveToFile()
    {
        Dictionary<Form1, int> d = new Dictionary<Form1, int>();

        byte[] data = new byte[laag_1.GetLength(0) * laag_1.GetLength(1) * 2];
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_1.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_1.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                int position = (y * laag_1.GetLength(0) + x);
                string value;
                switch (laag_1[x, y].BackColor.Name)
                {
                    case "Red":
                        value = "01";
                        break;
                    case "Black":
                        value = "00";
                        break;
                    case "Green":
                        value = "10";
                        break;
                    case "Yellow":
                        value = "11";
                        break;
                    default:
                        value = "00";
                        break;
                }
                data[2 * position] = (byte)value[0];
                data[2 * position + 1] = (byte)value[1];
            }
        }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data);
    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_1.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_1.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                laag_1[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_2.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_2.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                laag_2[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_3.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_3.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                laag_3[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_4.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_4.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                laag_4[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_5.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_5.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                laag_5[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_6.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_6.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                laag_6[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_7.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_7.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                laag_7[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < laag_8.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < laag_8.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                laag_8[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is all i have, i've tried to implement a future for read/write. But my knowledge of c# is just not enough to do anything about it.

Comment: you can look into [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx)

Comment: Actually you need to serialize the object to  file and then deserialize it and read the data :- http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the [File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) and [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) methods for saving and loading of the file.

Also take a look at the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) control for choosing what file to open.

Further, there's no need to be stingy with values, you can (and should) use a full byte for every button, just loop the buttons and insert the values in a byte[], and then write them out to a file.

Answer (score 1):

I assume You want to use *Object Serialization* for this.

*XMLSerialization*: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization
*BinarySerialization*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b(v=vs.71).aspx

If you want to save data and then read it by another application I am suggesting you a Serialization, because You don't have to worry about reading from file.

Comment: Binary serialization will be use full byte size instead of 2 bits only.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private const string filePath = @"d:\test.txt";
private void LoadFromFile()
{
    byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            int position = (x * btn.GetLength(1) + y) * 2;
            int index = position / 8;
            int shift = position % 8;

            byte value = (byte)((data[index] >> shift) % 4);
            Color color;
            switch (value)
            {
                case 1:
                    color = Color.Red;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    color = Color.Black;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    color = Color.Green;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    color = Color.Yellow;
                    break;
                default:
                    color = Color.Black;
                    break;
            }

            btn[x, y].BackColor = color;
        }
    }
}

private void SaveToFile()
{
    byte[] data = new byte[(7 + btn.GetLength(0) * btn.GetLength(1) * 2) / 8]; 
    for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            int position = (x * btn.GetLength(1) + y) * 2;
            byte value;
            switch (btn[x, y].BackColor.Name)
            {
                case "Red":
                    value = 1;
                    break;
                case "Black":
                    value = 0;
                    break;
                case "Green":
                    value = 2;
                    break;
                case "Yellow":
                    value = 3;
                    break;
                default:
                    value = 0;
                    break;
            }
            int index = position / 8;
            int shift = position % 8;
            data[index] = (byte)(data[index] | (value << shift));
        }
    }

    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data);
}
```

[Updated]:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button[,] btn = new Button[8, 8];
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    btn[x, y] = new Button();
                    btn[x, y].SetBounds((50 * x) + 30, (50 * y) + 30, 40, 40);
                    btn[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_click);
                    Controls.Add(btn[x, y]);
                    btn[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }

            this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(this.SaveEventHandler);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                LoadFromFile();
        }

        void btnEvent_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Control ctrl = ((Control)sender);
            switch (ctrl.BackColor.Name)
            {
                case "Red":
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    break;
                case "Black":
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
                case "Green":
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    break;
                case "Yellow":
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Black;
                    break;
                default:
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Black;
                    break;
            }
        }

        void SaveEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveToFile();
        }

        private const string filePath = @"d:\test.txt";
        private void LoadFromFile()
        {
            byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    int position = (x * btn.GetLength(1) + y) * 2;
                    int index = position / 8;
                    int shift = position % 8;

                    byte value = (byte)((data[index] >> shift) % 4);
                    Color color;
                    switch (value)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            color = Color.Red;
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            color = Color.Black;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            color = Color.Green;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            color = Color.Yellow;
                            break;
                        default:
                            color = Color.Black;
                            break;
                    }

                    btn[x, y].BackColor = color;
                }
            }
        }

        private void SaveToFile()
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[(7 + btn.GetLength(0) * btn.GetLength(1) * 2) / 8]; 
            for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    int position = (x * btn.GetLength(1) + y) * 2;
                    byte value;
                    switch (btn[x, y].BackColor.Name)
                    {
                        case "Red":
                            value = 1;
                            break;
                        case "Black":
                            value = 0;
                            break;
                        case "Green":
                            value = 2;
                            break;
                        case "Yellow":
                            value = 3;
                            break;
                        default:
                            value = 0;
                            break;
                    }
                    int index = position / 8;
                    int shift = position % 8;
                    data[index] = (byte)(data[index] | (value << shift));
                }
            }

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data);
        }
    }
}
```

[Update #2] Reworking storage as full byte for each led:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button[,] btn = new Button[8, 8];
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    btn[x, y] = new Button();
                    btn[x, y].SetBounds((50 * x) + 30, (50 * y) + 30, 40, 40);
                    btn[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_click);
                    Controls.Add(btn[x, y]);
                    btn[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }

            this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(this.SaveEventHandler);
            LoadFromFile();
        }

        void btnEvent_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Control ctrl = ((Control)sender);
            switch (ctrl.BackColor.Name)
            {
                case "Red":
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    break;
                case "Black":
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
                case "Green":
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    break;
                case "Yellow":
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Black;
                    break;
                default:
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Black;
                    break;
            }
        }

        void SaveEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveToFile();
        }

        private const string filePath = @"d:\test.txt";
        private void LoadFromFile()
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                return;

            byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            if (data == null || data.Length != btn.GetLength(0) * btn.GetLength(1))
                return;

            for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    int position = (y * btn.GetLength(0) + x);

                    char value = (char)data[position];
                    Color color;
                    switch (value)
                    {
                        case '1':
                            color = Color.Red;
                            break;
                        case '0':
                            color = Color.Black;
                            break;
                        case '2':
                            color = Color.Green;
                            break;
                        case '3':
                            color = Color.Yellow;
                            break;
                        default:
                            color = Color.Black;
                            break;
                    }

                    btn[x, y].BackColor = color;
                }
            }
        }

        private void SaveToFile()
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[btn.GetLength(0) * btn.GetLength(1)]; 
            for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    int position = (y * btn.GetLength(0) + x);
                    char value;
                    switch (btn[x, y].BackColor.Name)
                    {
                        case "Red":
                            value = '1';
                            break;
                        case "Black":
                            value = '0';
                            break;
                        case "Green":
                            value = '2';
                            break;
                        case "Yellow":
                            value = '3';
                            break;
                        default:
                            value = '0';
                            break;
                    }
                    data[position] = (byte)value;
                }
            }

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Update #3:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button[,] btn = new Button[8, 8];
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    btn[x, y] = new Button();
                    btn[x, y].SetBounds((50 * x) + 30, (50 * y) + 30, 40, 40);
                    btn[x, y].Click += new EventHandler(this.btnEvent_click);
                    Controls.Add(btn[x, y]);
                    btn[x, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }

            this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(this.SaveEventHandler);
            LoadFromFile();
        }

        void btnEvent_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Control ctrl = ((Control)sender);
            switch (ctrl.BackColor.Name)
            {
                case "Red":
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    break;
                case "Black":
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
                case "Green":
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    break;
                case "Yellow":
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Black;
                    break;
                default:
                    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Black;
                    break;
            }
        }

        void SaveEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveToFile();
        }

        private const string filePath = @"d:\test.txt";
        private void LoadFromFile()
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                return;

            byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            if (data == null || data.Length != btn.GetLength(0) * btn.GetLength(1) * 2)
                return;

            for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    int position = (y * btn.GetLength(0) + x);

                    string value = ((char)data[2 * position]).ToString() + ((char)data[2 * position + 1]).ToString();
                    Color color;
                    switch (value)
                    {
                        case "01":
                            color = Color.Red;
                            break;
                        case "00":
                            color = Color.Black;
                            break;
                        case "10":
                            color = Color.Green;
                            break;
                        case "11":
                            color = Color.Yellow;
                            break;
                        default:
                            color = Color.Black;
                            break;
                    }

                    btn[x, y].BackColor = color;
                }
            }
        }

        private void SaveToFile()
        {
            Dictionary<Form1, int> d = new Dictionary<Form1, int>();

            byte[] data = new byte[btn.GetLength(0) * btn.GetLength(1) * 2]; 
            for (int x = 0; x < btn.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < btn.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    int position = (y * btn.GetLength(0) + x);
                    string value;
                    switch (btn[x, y].BackColor.Name)
                    {
                        case "Red":
                            value = "01";
                            break;
                        case "Black":
                            value = "00";
                            break;
                        case "Green":
                            value = "10";
                            break;
                        case "Yellow":
                            value = "11";
                            break;
                        default:
                            value = "00";
                            break;
                    }
                    data[2 * position] = (byte)value[0];
                    data[2 * position + 1] = (byte)value[1];
                }
            }

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, looks really good.
When is the file saved? if i close the application or is there a button needed to save the file?
And where is the file saved?

Comment: this save to file which provided into following constant: private const string filePath = @"d:\test.txt"; In my example this saved into "d:\test.txt". Configuration will be saved when you invoke function SaveToFile() and loaded when you invokes function LoadFromFile(). You should add these invokations to you application in place where you need.

Comment: Ok I adjusted it to : C:\testmap\test.txt.
But when i close the application there is no file showing up.

Comment: You should use Form closing event. Added following line into Form1 constructor: this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(this.SaveEventHandler); And define SaveEventHandler function:
         void SaveEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveToFile();
        }

Comment: Where exactly do i need to put that line of code?

Comment: If you also need automatically loading add following line into end of Form1 constructor: if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)) LoadFromFile();

Comment: Do i need to put those 2 lines of code in the Form1.cs file?
And where exactly, cause i get alot of errors when i put it somewhere

Comment: Try updated version with events.

Comment: Alright it works now.
the save file is written in Hexadecimal right?
Could it be like a total of 64 values (1 for each led)?
So if the first row is red red green green yellow yellow black black.
It should be : 1 1 2 2 3 3 0 0

Comment: It stored as bits. If you need readable text file required store as 2 bytes instead of 2 bits values. But this required a new global code update. I think that you main requirement store as bits instead of bytes. If change what you whant it change file size from 16 bytes to 64bytes.

Comment: Alright, i get it.
So the total possibilities for 4 bytes (4 leds) are 4^4= 256 right?
That means i have to define the code for 256 possibilities and just copy that code for the other 128 (groups of LED's)? Total 512 leds, its a cube of 8x8

Comment: 1 led is 2 bits, 4 leds is a 1 byte. 8x8 cube is 64 leds (16 bytes).

Comment: Oh ok, sorry i meant 8x8x8.

Comment: I added one more update please check it maybe same as you whant.

Comment: Wow looks really nice.
I was wondering if it could be in 128 bit? in binary.
So for example:  00 - 01 - 10 - 11  (for every led. so 2 x 64 = 128)
                 out - red - green - yellow
I've tried it myself but the code you provided is just to complicated for me. I'd be awsome if you could help me with this.

Comment: could you give some help to set the data to binary (01 for red, 10 for green, 11 for yellow and 00 for black?)

Comment: Use first updated version, it stored as binary.

Comment: Mhhh.... It doesn't show up as a binary in the text file. It's just some weird signs. If i use a program to read Hexadecimal files it shows up as 05 0 05 0 05 0 05 0.
It it possible to have the text in the text file like this:
01 00 01 00 01 00 01 00

Comment: Wow thank you so much man! You are my savior!

Comment: I have 1 more little question (final one i promise).
i've added 7 more layers next to eachother. How can i let it save in 1024 bits (512 leds, and 00-01-10-11 for each led).

Comment: i've changed the code (at the top of this screen).
This is the code i'm using now